# Does riding Lloid cause it to deal more damage on impact?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

With Villager's side B, does actually riding the rocket powered gyroid cause it to be stronger/blast the opponent further?

Comment: This is actually one of the in-game tips

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. Riding it will cause around 10-20 percent more damage depending on the distance away. After I tested it in training mode, riding it caused 16 percent damage as opposed to 7 percent when not riding it.